# jtextfield cursor blinking too fast and doesn't register input at times

Tags: java, timer, cursor, jtextfield

Hi I'm creating a program where the user needs to give certain inputs to gain points and there is a timer, but the timer is I created is making the cursor in the jtextfield to blink too fast for the program to take inputs at times. In my timer class I imported TimerTask and used timer.scheduleAtFixedRate() to count time. This isn't all my code but this is the main class.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class Interface extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private JTextField textField;
private int fontSize;
private Font font;
private GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
private int x, y;
private collection userInputData;
private boolean initialized = false;
private String[] answers;
private String[] questions;
private int points = 0;

private timer timer;

private boolean timerStarted = false;

Interface() {
    super(new GridBagLayout());
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    userInputData = new collection();
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);


    timer = new timer(60);

    questions = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

    answers = new String[] {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g" };

    /*questions = new String[] {"云", "人", "口", "一"};

    answers = new String[] {"去","十","二","大","运","中","丁" };*/

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    fontSize = getWidth() / 25;
    Font font = new Font(g.getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, fontSize);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    if(initialized){
        updateUserDataFrame();
        updateFrame();
        textField.requestFocus();
    }
    if (!timer.timeUp()) {
        questions(g);
        fontSize = getWidth() / 50;
        Font n = new Font(g.getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, fontSize);
        g.setFont(n);
        displayTimer(g);
        points(g);
        displayUserInput(g);
    }

    if (timer.timeUp()) {
        displayScoreboard(g);
        remove(textField);
    }

}

private void displayTimer(Graphics g) {
    if (!timerStarted) {
        timer.start();
        timerStarted = true;
    }

    //fontSize = getWidth() / 35;
    timer.setColor(Color.RED);
    timer.setPosition(getWidth() - (int) (getWidth() ), fontSize );
    timer.displayTimer(g);

    repaint();
}

private void displayScoreboard(Graphics g) {
    int x = getWidth() / 50;
    int y = getHeight() / 5;
    g.drawString("Your Answers:", x, y);
   /* String correctWrongNumber = "Correct: " + correctAnswers + "   "
            + "Wrong: " + (question.length - correctAnswers);
    x = getWidth() - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(correctWrongNumber) - getWidth() / 25;
    g.drawString(correctWrongNumber, x, y);
    x = getWidth() / 50;
    y += getHeight() / 15 + fontSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswers.length; i++) {
        g.drawString(i + 1 + ". " + studentAnswers[i], x, y);
        x += getWidth() / 10.5;
    }*/

}

private void points(Graphics g) {
    int x = getWidth() / 4;
    int y = getHeight() / 4;
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString("Points: " + points, x, y);
}

private void questions( Graphics g) {
    int x = getWidth() / 4;
    int y = getHeight() / 8;
    int borderY = getHeight() /60;
    fontSize = getWidth() / 15;
    Font font = new Font(g.getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, fontSize);
    g.setFont(font);
    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

        g.setColor(Color.red.brighter());
        g.fillRect(x + 1, borderY, fontSize, fontSize);
        g.setColor(Color.orange.brighter());
        g.drawRect(x, borderY, fontSize, fontSize);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(questions[i],x,y);
        x += getWidth() / 6;
    }

}

private void updateFrame() {

    fontSize = getWidth() / 20;
    font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize);
    textField.setFont(font);
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, getHeight() / 2, 0);
    remove(textField);
    add(textField, c);
}

private void updateUserDataFrame(){
    int x = getWidth()/60;
    int y = getHeight()/3 + getHeight()/20;
    int width = getWidth()/16;
    int height = getWidth()/16;
    int fontSize = getWidth()/20;
    Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize);

    userInputData.reset();
    while(userInputData.hasNext()){
        structure temp = (structure)userInputData.next();
        x += getWidth()/16;
        temp.updateData(font, x, y, width, height);
    }
}

private void displayUserInput(Graphics g) {
    userInputData.paint(g);

}

void init(){
    x = getWidth()/60;
    y = getHeight()/3 + getHeight()/20;
    fontSize = getWidth()/20;
    font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, fontSize);

    textField = new JTextField(3);
    textField.setFont(font);
    textField.addActionListener(this);
    //Add Components to this panel.
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, getHeight()/2, 0);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    add(textField, c);
    updateUI();
    initialized = true;
    repaint();


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int buttonWidth = getWidth()/16;
    int buttonHeight = getWidth()/16;
    x += getWidth()/16;
    String userInput = textField.getText();
    for(int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        if(answers[i].equals(textField.getText()))
            points++;
    }
    userInputData.add(new structure(userInput, Color.WHITE, font,x,y,buttonWidth,buttonHeight));
    textField.setText("");
    repaint();
}
}
```

Edited: Timer class

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

class timer {
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private int timeLimit;
private int x, y;
private Color color;
private TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        timeLimit--;
        if(timeLimit == 0){
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
};

timer() {
    timeLimit = 120;
}

timer(int limit) {
    timeLimit = limit;
}

void start() {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
}

void displayTimer(Graphics g) {
    int minute = timeLimit / 60;
    int second = timeLimit % 60;
    g.setColor(color);
    if (minute < 10) {
        if (second < 10)
            g.drawString("0" + minute + ":0" + second, x, y);

        else
            g.drawString("0" + minute + ":" + second, x, y);

    } else {
        if (second < 10)
            g.drawString(minute + ":0" + second, x, y);

        else
            g.drawString(minute + ":" + second, x, y);

    }
}

void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}

void setPosition(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

int getTime() {
    return timeLimit;
}

void setTime(int time) {
    timeLimit = time;
}

boolean timeUp() {
    return timeLimit == 0;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand where this `timer` is coming from ? You can use this code `Timer timer = new Timer(1000,this);` instead of `timer timer = new timer(60);`

Making 1000 enable to you use real timer.

I hope this make life your easier a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I made a separate timer class. I'll add it in.